# List of listings: problem with the STYLE of table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, listings

I have some problems with making of table of contents for listings.
I would like to add to my document (`memoir` class) the `List of Listings` but I could only obtain it with totally a different style from the other figures and tabular in table of contents. Here you can see the "effect" and a piece of code.
Could anybody help me? Thanks a lot.

[image]

```
 %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PREAMBOLO
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,twoside,openleft]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Pacchetti ed impostazioni generali

\usepackage{plain}
\usepackage{setspace}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%------------------------- NENA  layout ----------------------
% Better page layout for A4 paper, see memoir manual.
\settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt} 
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth} 
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth} 
\settypeblocksize{634pt}{448.13pt}{*} 
\setulmargins{4cm}{*}{*} 
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5} 
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{51pt}{\onelineskip} 
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip} 
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*} 
\checkandfixthelayout
%
\frenchspacing
% Font with math support: New Century Schoolbook
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% Sets numbering division level
\setsecnumdepth{subsection} 
\maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
%
\usepackage{float}                      %Helps to place figures, tables, etc. 
%\newfloat{algo}{tbp}{loa}[chapter]

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{calc,soul,fourier}
\makeatletter 
\newlength\dlf@normtxtw 
\setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth} 
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter} 
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
    \sbox\feline@chapter{% 
        \resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
            \colorbox{gray}{\color{white}\thechapter}% 
        }}%
        \rotatebox{90}{% 
            \resizebox{%
                \heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}% 
            {!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
        \raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
} 
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
    \sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}% 
    \makebox[0pt][c]{% aka \rlap
        \makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
    }}
\makechapterstyle{daleifmodif}{
    \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so} 
    \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\scshape} 
    \renewcommand\chapternamenum{} \renewcommand\printchaptername{} 
    \renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par} 
    \renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip} 
    \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\color{gray}\chaptitlefont\raggedleft ##1\par}
} 
\makeatother 
\chapterstyle{daleifmodif}
%
% The pages should be numbered consecutively at the bottom centre of the
% page.
\makepagestyle{myvf} 
\makeoddfoot{myvf}{}{\thepage}{} 
\makeevenfoot{myvf}{}{\thepage}{} 
\makeheadrule{myvf}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness} 
\makeevenhead{myvf}{\small\textsc{\leftmark}}{}{} 
\makeoddhead{myvf}{}{}{\small\textsc{\rightmark}}
\pagestyle{myvf}
%
\makeindex
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
%
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

%Formato titolo
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:\ }
  {0pt}
  {\filcenter}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{40pt}{40pt}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openleft\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{\par}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\addto\captionsitalian{% 
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Codice}}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DOCUMENTO
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Frontespizio

 \pagenumbering{gobble} 
 \input{pagina_iniziale}
 \clearpage

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Se si volesse aggiungere anche elenco tabelle
    \newpage
    \listoftables

    \newpage  
    \lstlistoflistings
%    \newpage

%**********************************************************************
% DEFINIZIONE TITOLI ED INDENTATURE
\titleformat{\chapter}
        {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}

      \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0in}{0.1in}
      \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0.20in}{0.1in}
      \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0.10in}{0.08in}
      \titlespacing*{\paragraph}{5mm}{0.02in}{5mm}
      \titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0.02in}{0in}


%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LISTA DEI CAPITOLI     
% %      \input{Agenda/Agenda}  

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `titlesec` and `memoir` is surely not a good combination and most likely using both there is the cause of your problems

Comment: Hi, thank you for your kindly answer. How could I handle both of them together? I would like to keep memoir style for list of figure, listings and table and titlesec for chapter, section and paragraph. Is it possible?